# Variables local to Functions in different shell script interpreters

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to increase portability of a script, so it runs in various interpreters (alas, each comes with its opinion on the standards and generations thereof). Currently the test suite tries to run the same code in `bash`, `dash`/`ash`, `zsh`, `busybox sh`, `ksh` as available in Debian Linux, and `bash`, `zsh`, `ksh88` and `ksh93` for Solaris/illumos.

While most of the constructs can be driven to lowest common denominator (and I even got it to use e.g. shell regexp support where available or fall back to external `grep`/`sed`/`awk` where I need it to just work), there is a particular hiccup with recursively called functions - and variables whose values each layer wants to keep local. Unfortunately, at least some of the KSH interpreters in the equation do not support the `local` keyword at all, their equivalent is `typeset varname` or `typeset var varname` or even might require `typeset varname=initialValue`. I did manage to work around this by `eval` based on detected shell interpreter, roughly like this:

```
# there is really a bit more magic to try and detect a shell interpreter
if [ -z "${LOCALKEYWORD-}" ]; then
    LOCALKEYWORD="typeset var"
    [ -n "${BASH-}" ] && LOCALKEYWORD="local"
fi

x=4
y=5
test() {
    eval $LOCALKEYWORD x
    y=$(expr $y + 1)
    x=$(expr $x + 1)
    echo "INSIDE:  $x $y"
}

echo "OUTSIDE: $x $y"
test
echo "OUTSIDE: $x $y"
test
echo "OUTSIDE: $x $y"
```

In this script's output one should see the "outside" values print `4 (y+1)` while the "inside" values are `1 (y+1)` as the `x` is reinitialized with locality (starts empty, then the `expr` math sets it to `1`) while `y` is inherited.

The `busybox sh` in this case inherits the caller's `x` value as well, so it serves `5 (y+1)` for the "inside" reports, and I guess it can be argued reasonable (so one must initialize local variables to predictable values, no problem).

Unfortunately, I found that the KSH locality only works for "real" function declarations, spelled as `function name { ... ; }` - with the `function` keyword and no `()` parentheses after the name. However, some shells (`busybox sh` and `dash`) barf on this syntax and do not accept a `function` as a valid keyword:

```
function test2 {
    echo YES
}

./local.sh: line 19: function: not found
YES
./local.sh: line 21: syntax error: unexpected "}"
```

So I tried to wrap it even further:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "${LOCALKEYWORD-}" ]; then
    LOCALKEYWORD="typeset var"
    #LOCALKEYWORD="declare"
    [ -n "${BASH-}" ] && LOCALKEYWORD=local
fi
x=4
y=5

test_att() {
    eval $LOCALKEYWORD x
    y=$(expr $y + 1)
    x=$(expr $x + 1)
    echo "INSIDE:  $x $y"
}

if [ "$LOCALKEYWORD" != local ]; then
    test() {
        function test_ksh { test_att "$@"; }
        test_ksh "$@"
    }
else
    test() { test_att "$@"; }
fi

echo "OUTSIDE: $x $y"
test
echo "OUTSIDE: $x $y"
test
echo "OUTSIDE: $x $y"
```

And this surprisingly works... almost.

```
for SHELL_PROG in bash dash zsh "busybox sh" ksh ; do
    for LOCALKEYWORD in "typeset var" "typeset" "local"; do
        echo "=== $SHELL_PROG with $LOCALKEYWORD"
        (export LOCALKEYWORD; $SHELL_PROG ./local.sh)
        echo ""
    done
    echo ""
done
```

Bash has no problem with either syntax (can do both KSH `function name {}` and AT&T `name() {}` as well as both `typeset` and `local`); `zsh` seems to be similarly omnivorous for this example, both producing

```
OUTSIDE: 4 5
INSIDE:  1 6
OUTSIDE: 4 6
INSIDE:  1 7
OUTSIDE: 4 7
```

for each of the three cases.

The `ksh` works for `typeset` variants and breaks for `local`, as expected as this started the adventure.

Unfortunately, `busybox sh` and `dash` still both refuse to parse the `if`ed-away routine:

```
./local.sh: 23: ./local.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

If I comment away the `function test_ksh { test_att "$@"; }` line, the variants for `typeset` codepaths fail (so KSH support is lost), but `busybox sh` and `dash` both begin to work (inheriting the caller's value of `x`, so it should be initialized in the function, but the caller's value is not replaced as expected per requested locality).

I hope that someone helps me get around this latter issue, and feel free to use the tricks above in your work. I'm actually surprised I got this far at least ;)

Jim

Comment: As a sort of reminder to myself and possibly an answer (needs checking), I found this gist recently : https://gist.github.com/bk2204/9dd24df0e4499a02a300578ebdca4728